# Canvas - Fill a rectangle in all areas that are fully transparent

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, composite, clipping

I'm writing a simple 2D game engine using the HTML5 canvas. I've come to adding a lighting engine. Each light source has a radius value and an intensity value (0-1, eg 1 would be very bright). There's also an ambient light value that is used to light everything else in the world that isn't  near a light source (0-1, eg 0.1 would be moonlight). The process of lighting is done on a separate canvas above the main canvas:

1. For each light source, a radial gradient is drawn at that position with the same radius as the light source. The gradient is given two stops: the center is black with an alpha of 1-intensity of the light and the end/edge is black with alpha of 1-ambient light value. That all works fine.
2. This is where it goes wrong :/ I need to fill the whole canvas with black with and alpha of 1-ambient light value and at the moment I do this by setting the context.globalCompositeOperation to source-out then fillRecting the whole canvas.

My code for this stuff is:

```
var amb = 'rgba(0,0,0,' + (1-f.ambientLight) + ')';
for(i in f.entities) {
    var e = f.entities[i], p = f.toScreenPoint(e.position.x, e.position.y), radius = e.light.radius;

    if(radius > 0) {
        var g = cxLighting.createRadialGradient(p.x, p.y, 0, p.x, p.y, radius);
        g.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(0,0,0,' + (1-e.light.intensity) + ')');
        g.addColorStop(1, amb);

        cxLighting.fillStyle = g;
        cxLighting.beginPath();
        cxLighting.arc(p.x, p.y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        cxLighting.closePath();
        cxLighting.fill();
    }
}
//Ambient light
cxLighting.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-out';
cxLighting.fillStyle = amb;
cxLighting.fillRect(0, 0, f.width, f.height);
cxLighting.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
```

However instead of getting what I wan't out of the engine (left) I get a kind of reversed gradient (right). I think this is because when I draw the rectangle with the `source-out` composite operation it affects the colours of the gradient itself because they are semi-transparent.
[image: Desired lighting effect]
[image: I get this]

Is there a way to do this differently or better? Using clipping maybe, or drawing the rect over everything first?

Also, I modified the Mozila Dev Centre's [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Compositing) on composting to replicate what I need to do and none of the composite modes seemed to work, [check that out](http://chopapp.com/#1b0f6c3e) if it would help.

Thanks very much, any answer would be great :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One trivial way would be to use `imageData` but that would be painfully slow. It's an option, but not a good one for a game engine.

Another way would be to think of the ambient light and the light-source as if they were one path. That would make it very easy to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/HADky/

Or see it with an image behind: http://jsfiddle.net/HADky/10/

The thing you're taking advantage of here is the fact that any intersection of a path on canvas is always only unioned and never compounded. So you're using a single gradient brush to draw the whole thing.

But it gets a bit trickier than that if there's more than one light-source. I'm not too sure how to cover that in an efficient way, especially if you plan for two light-sources to intersect.

What you should probably do instead is devise an alpha channel instead of this overlay thing, but I can't currently think of a good way to get it to work. I'll revisit this if I think of anything else.

---

**EDIT:** Hey! So I've done a bit of thinking and came up with a good solution.

What you need to do is draw a sort of alpha channel, where the dark spots mark the places where you want light to be. So if you had three light sources it would look like this:

[image]

Then you want to set the fill style to your ambient color and set the globalCompositeOperation to xor and xor the whole thing.

```
ctx.fillStyle = amb;
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,500,500);
```

That will leave you with the "opposite" image except the transparent parts will be correctly ambient:

[image]

Here's a working example of the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/a2Age/

Extra optimization: You can actually achieve the effect without using any paths at all, by simply drawing the exact same radial gradients onto rects instead of circular paths:

http://jsfiddle.net/a2Age/2/
Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I've put that into my code and it works great mostly, But seems to fall down [when the intensity of a light source is < 1](http://jsfiddle.net/ve2jy/) and also when you start to [increase the ambient light](http://jsfiddle.net/vnurX/) the lights themselves seem to disappear much quicker than they should, like the ambient light is having more effect than it should. I'm guessing these problems are to do with the XOR mode. Thanks anyway, definitely a big step in the right direcion

Comment: I wish i could upvote more than once, this answer made my day. been trying for AGES to blur a canvas shape, to no avail. tried exporting images etc and bluring them. 

Your solution is exactly what i needed but the search gods dont know that `ctx.createRadialGradient()` is the same as bluring a shape/circle.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, but since you're getting the opposite effect you're going for from your gradient, have you tried reversing the gradient?