# Canvas - Clear Circular Gradient

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I have a canvas that sits above some content and is filled completely with black to allow the users to reveal things below the canvas. I would like to clear a circle at a predetermined location, but I'd like the circle fade into the fill color. [I've found how to clear circles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396991/clearing-circular-regions-from-html5-canvas), but I am unable to locate anything that lets me clear a circle that fades to the background color.

---

Current Code - Clears a Circle, But Does not Fade to Black

```
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.clip();
    context.clearRect(x - radius - 1, y - radius - 1, radius * 2 + 2, radius * 2 + 2);
```

---

Code Tried - Doesn't Work

```
    var radGrd = context.createRadialGradient(x, y, r1, x, y, r2);
    radGrd.addColorStop(0, "rgba( 0, 0, 0,  0 )");
    radGrd.addColorStop(1, "rgba( 0, 0, 0,  1 )");

    //Doesn't Work; Nothing Draws On Screen
    context.fillStyle = radGrd;
    context.clip();
    context.clearRect(x - r2, y - r2, r2 * 2, r2 * 2);
```

---

**Q: What is the correct way to clear a circle that fades into the background color?**

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it: after the `clearRect`, add a `fillRect` command with the same parameters. You should remove `arc` or `clip` commands, since you're filling a *rectangle* with a circular gradient.

Comment: Please see my follow up post about a related problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320784/cavnas-overlapping-radial-gradient-clears