# how to use transparent effect for only a part of the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, imagemap, jquery-hover

I am not sure if it is possible. But let's say there are two images, one over another. Then I will have a circle size 100px around my cursor. So when I move the cursor over the image, it shows part of image that is under the front image. So the back image is hidden and visible only if the circle size 100px is over some part of it.

Unfortunately I have no code as I am not sure if it is possible to create.

However, any idea about it?

Comment: You may use HTML5 canvas for this effect..

Answer (score 2):

I would try actually stacking the hidden image above the visible one, then use HTML5's canvas to track your mouse cursor, clip a circular area underneath your cursor, then draw your image above it. This gives the illusion that you're "revealing" an underlying image, when in fact you're really revealing a small portion of an image stacked on top. Repeat this any time the user moves his/her cursor.

Here are some resources you might find useful in coding this:

[HTML5 Canvas Clipping Region Tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-clipping-region-tutorial/)

[HTML5 Canvas Mouse Coordinates](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates/)

Stack Overflow: [clearing circular regions from HTML5 Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396991/clearing-circular-regions-from-html5-canvas)