# Can I fill a rectangle with a transparent gradient javascript canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to overlay this black rectangle:

[image]

By filling another rectangle of the same size on top of it that has a semi-transparent, gradient paint (should look something like this):

[image]

I know I can do a transparent paint with the following:

```
g2d.fillStyle = "rgba(100, 3, 3, 0.5)";
```

I also know how to do a gradient paint:

```
var grd=g2d.createLinearGradient(0,0,200,0);
grd.addColorStop(0,"red");
grd.addColorStop(1,"blue");
g2d.fillStyle=grd;
```

However, I do not know how to combine both the gradient and transparency properties together as one paint to use on my rectangle. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you just do them on the same canvas one after the other, it will automatically create the desired output.

Comment: @PeteB I doubt it, wouldn't the gradient one simply cover over the original rectangle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909865/canvas-fill-a-rectangle-in-all-areas-that-are-fully-transparent this might help you

Comment: @AshwinGupta oh I see, yes you need to set the alpha property for the second fill, check out ctx.globalAlpha

Comment: @Atula ah yes, `g.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(0,0,0,' + (1-e.light.intensity) + ')');`. Should've thought about using an rgba color as one of the stops... duh! TY.

Comment: @PeteB oh yep, that looks like it would work also. TY very much, both you and Atula have provided me with useful information and good ways to solve the problem. Now I'll just have to decide what implementation works best in my case. (I assume I can just temporarily set the global to 0.5 then set it right back to 1?)

Comment: No problems, have fun!  If you use globalAlpha bear in mind it is in fact 'global' so it's good practise to switch it back to 1.0 after you've finished the transparent part of your drawing. EDIT: LOL I see you realised that already in an edit while I was typing :)

Comment: I have always found it odd that people treat global alpha with the need to constantly restore it. Would it be as urgent if it did not have the global prefix. It is after all just as global as any other context setting, like the text, font, line, fill, stroke, shadow,  etc, etc... all globals.... The global in globalAlpha refers to that fact that all pixels that are rendered are multiplied by it, not that it has any particular ongoing global effect beyond that of any other setting

Comment: @Blindman67 I see what you are saying, the word global does certainly have a ring to it that causes a bit of obsessive panic. However, IMO it is still important to have it reset somewhere because its cleaner then constantly specifying it to 1.0 for every object that is painted regularly.

Comment: @AshwinGupta yes, but just do it for every properties. Also, if your problem is solved, you may want to delete your question since it sounds as a temporary gap in mind, and may not help anyone coming in future. If you do think otherwise, you can still self-answer it.

Comment: @Kaiido okay, I'll just self answer it combining what the others told me that way it could help people in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:

#### Global alpha

Set global (consider it a "master alpha") right before drawing something:

```
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;  // [0, 1]
ctx.fillRect( ... );
```

#### Color alpha

Or define the colors themselves with alphas:

```
grd.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255,0,0, 0.5)");  // 50% alpha
grd.addColorStop(1, "rgba(0,0,255, 0.5)");
```

*Worth to notice*: if you use the latter approach and for example set 0% opacity on one end, the color will still matter as it is interpolated to the point where it becomes fully transparent. In the meanwhile the color definition will bleed through. I.e. don't just set black (unless black is what you need).

Answer (score 0):

First draw the gradient:

```
var grd=g2d.createLinearGradient(0,0,200,0);
grd.addColorStop(0,"red");
grd.addColorStop(1,"blue");
g2d.fillStyle=grd;
```

Then draw the semi-transparent background:

```
g2d.fillStyle = "rgba(200,0,0,0.5)";
g2d.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
```